# Translation on Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have a 2D matrix as such: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 &0\\
0 &1 &0\\
0 &0 &1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If I apply a rotation of 180 degrees and a scale of 2, what will my resultant matrix look like? Also, given another matrix (example below), how do I get the angle it was rotated and the scale?

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1.4 &0.12 &0\\
-0.12 &1.4 &0\\
0 &0 &1.0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I apologise in advance- I'm not a math major and this is most definitely not homework. I just want to apply this knowledge in transforming images (I'm making an app). Thanks!

Comment: Rotation about an anticlockwise angle $\theta$ is given by $\begin{pmatrix}\cos\,\theta&-\sin\,\theta\\\sin\,\theta&\cos\,\theta\end{pmatrix}$, while scaling by a factor of $p$ in the horizontal and a factor of $q$ in the vertical is represented by $\begin{pmatrix}p&0\\0&q\end{pmatrix}$. So, in most cases, you have to specify the direction of rotation, and which of the two transformations will you be applying first. Luckily for you, since $p=q$ in your case, the order doesn't matter...

Comment: "Also, given another matrix (example below), how do I get the angle it was rotated and the scale?" - you'll want to look up what is called the QR decomposition.

Comment: thanks jm. so i guess getting the angle and scale is a pretty difficult process. what if we know that p and q will be the same all the time?

Comment: If you know the matrix is always of the form $\begin{pmatrix}p\,\cos\,\theta&-p\,\sin\,\theta\\p\,\sin\,\theta&p\,\cos\,\theta\end{pmatrix}$, then just take the square root of the sum of the squares of the entries in the first row to get $p$ (why?). Divide all the entries of the matrix by $p$ to obtain the rotation matrix.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: http://xkcd.com/184/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A= $\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 &0\\
0 &1 &0\\
0 &0 &1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

B$_{+180}$= $\begin{bmatrix}
cos(180 )&sin(180) &0\\
-sin(180) &cos(180 ) &0\\
0 &0 &1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

C$_{2,2}$= $\begin{bmatrix}
2 &0 &0\\
0 &2 &0\\
0 &0 &1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

ABC = $\begin{bmatrix}
-2 &0 &0\\
0 &-2 &0\\
0 &0 &1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
(Assuming rotation is clockwise)